# Oracle Application Continuity - Not Able to get Replay DataSouce

Tags: datasource, oracle12c, replay, continuity

I am not able to get the replayable datasource (Code is attached below).

```
    PoolDataSource  pds = PoolDataSourceFactory.getPoolDataSource();
                                 pds.setConnectionFactoryClassName("oracle.jdbc.replay.OracleDataSourceImpl");

                                 System.out.println("connection factory set");

                                 String URL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION = (TRANSPORT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT=3) (RETRY_COUNT=20)(FAILOVER=ON) " +
                                  " (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521)) (CONNECT_DATA = " +
                                  " (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME=orcl)))";
                                 System.out.println("Using URL\n" + URL);
                                 pds.setURL(URL);
                                 pds.setUser("system");
                                 pds.setPassword("oracle");

                                 pds.setInitialPoolSize(10);
                                 pds.setMinPoolSize(10);
                                 pds.setMaxPoolSize(20);
                                 pds.setConnectionWaitTimeout(10);
                                 // RAC Features
                                 pds.setConnectionPoolName("Application Continuity Pool");
                                 pds.setFastConnectionFailoverEnabled(true);

                                 System.out.println("pool configured, trying to get a connection");

                                 Connection conn = null;

                                 try{
                                           conn = pds.getConnection();
                                 }catch(Exception e){
                                           e.printStackTrace();
                                 }

                                 if (conn == null || !((ValidConnection) conn).isValid())  {

                                   System.out.println("connection is not valid");
                                   throw new Exception ("invalid connection obtained from the pool");
                                 }

                                 if ( conn instanceof oracle.jdbc.replay.ReplayableConnection ) {
                                   System.out.println("got a replay data source");
                                 } else {
                                   System.out.println("this is not a replay data source. Why not?");
                                 }
```

Below is the System Prints I am getting out from above code, which show the connection instance is not of replayable type.

> connection factory set Using URL jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION =
>   (TRANSPORT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT=3) (RETRY_COUNT=20)(FAILOVER=ON)  (ADDRESS
>   = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521)) (CONNECT_DATA =  (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = orcl))) pool configured, trying
>   **to get a connection this is not a replay data source. Why not?**

I got the code from below site and modified a bit to add threads and simulate AC. But I am unable to get a replayable datasource.

https://martincarstenbach.wordpress.com/2013/12/13/playing-with-application-continuity-in-rac-12c/

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have oracle.jdbc.replay.OracleDataSourceImpl in your classpath, in other words, please make sure you have the 12.1.0.2 JDBC driver in your classpath.